# How to change flycheck symbol?, like spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, customize, flycheck

Flycheck has a symbol that tells in which line an error or warning have been encountered. I have seen spacemacs has its flycheck symbol changed. Default symbol is a double arrow; while spacemacs's symbol is a dot. I can't find a function to change it. How did spacemacs do that?

[image: Spacemacs flycheck symbol looks like this (red dot)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading flycheck source code..

1. You must define a fringe bitmap (the "symbol") with 'define-fringe-bitmap' function.
2. Use 'flycheck-define-error-level' function to load the new bitman
3. Enable Flycheck mode

Example:

```
(define-fringe-bitmap 'flycheck-fringe-bitmap-ball
    (vector #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00111000
            #b01111100
            #b11111110
            #b11111110
            #b01111100
            #b00111000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000
            #b00000000))

(flycheck-define-error-level 'error
  :severity 100
  :compilation-level 2
  :overlay-category 'flycheck-error-overlay
  :fringe-bitmap 'flycheck-fringe-bitmap-ball
  :fringe-face 'flycheck-fringe-error
  :error-list-face 'flycheck-error-list-error)
```

Edit: removed extra ')'

Comment: It worked, thanks. For those interested, for warnings and info just replace all "error" words with "warning" and "info" of ``flycheck-define-error-level``.

Comment: Also, I used 2, 1 and 0 for severity of errors, warnings and info respectively.